# EasyMock problem, calling method on instance but not interested in how to get this instance

Tags: java, easymock

I'm trying to test an algorithm with Easymock but I'm stumbling into the details of the implementation of this algorithm.  Someone who can provide me a way out?  The part which gives me a problem is this:

```
interface A {
 B getB ();
}

interface B {
  void setX (int x);
  void doSomething ();
}
```

Now somewhere during the algorithm under test this happens:

```
a.getB ().setX (9);
a.getB ().doSomething ();
a.getB ().setX (16);
```

This results in an unexpected method call getB () as my test only declares the interesting part:

```
B b = EasyMock.createStrictControl ();
b.setX (9);
EasyMock.expectLastCall();
b.doSomething ();
EasyMock.expectLastCall();
```

I understand this is because the order is checked.  But even when I place the following line nothing changes.

```
EasyMock.expect (a.getB ()).andReturn (b).anyTimes ();
```

The instance a is also an EasyMock proxy.

Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Use `anyTimes()` as per your last bit of code, but don't use strict mocks - it's the strictness which is enforcing the ordering.

Admittedly I can't remember the details of how EasyMock handles ordering *between* controls, but it sounds like you're really not bothered about the ordering.

Comment: I am bothered by the order of the methods of interface B but not about the order of where I call getB () on A.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `andStubReturn (b)` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me fine.  I am using strict mocks but I don't have any experience with the `createStrictControl()` method.

```
B b = EasyMock.createStrictMock(B.class);
A a = EasyMock.createStrictMock(A.class);
expect(a.getB()).andReturn(b).anyTimes();

b.setX(9);
b.doSomething();
b.setX(16);

replay(a);
replay(b);
a.getB().setX(9);
a.getB().doSomething();
a.getB().setX(16);
verify(b);
verify(a);
```